# git commands and install freeze git bash won't open

Tags: windows, git, bash

Installing `git` ver 2.15.0 and 2.14.2 on Windows 10 freezes before finishing the install. The only way to close the install window is to kill the process or restart my machine.

After restarting, git Bash will open but it opens in a frozen state. If I try to run commands from an Admin Windows command prompt, *some* of them work but `git push` and `git stash` also just hang there, and do nothing.

I've search around and have found that others have problems with git on Windows 10 but haven't found any solutions.

Any suggestions or is there any type of error logging with git?
Thanks

Comment: Those are some rather simple commands with a low overhead.  I would be more concerned with how your Win10 box is setup or maybe even you network or even the remote side of things where your git repos are installed.  Try hooking up to git hub, check any type of network restrictions.  I am using Win10 box with Git and all the above no issues

Comment: The repo is ok, other users aren't having this problem. I also tried the `react` repo from github and have the same problem running `git stash`. I'm an admin user... any idea what network restrictions could cause this?

Comment: I wish there were some feedback in the cmd window. The cursor moves to the next line and just sits there. Is there any type of log file with `git` that I can check?